# obtain a table/chart design overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been wondering for the past few days on how to obtain such as design as the one attached below. First of all, my concern is the "sparkline/area" chart at the bottom of the `table/divs`.

I can't wrap my head around on how I can code something like this. The chart data should "overlap" each div - how is that done? Should I maybe use a `table`?

Could someone, please try to help me out here. A quick code example on how to obtain the overlapping effect would help tremendous.

If this post doesn't belong on Stackoverflow, please accept my apologies. 
[image: My goal]

Comment: please show your attempts in a fiddle

Comment: the charts are probably done in 2 seperate html5 canvas's, that would be the easiest way probably. One would have a higher z-index the other one 2 below. The divs would have a z-index between the other 2.

Comment: @Lenny Aha. But the divs which container the charts, should that be one large div, or 5 small ones (in order to container the charts like the reference)

Comment: @oliverbj 5 small ones

Comment: I've played arround a bit. This chart should not be made like in the fiddle, but you get the idea. http://jsfiddle.net/bnPDS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use z-index to position element above/below other elements:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">One</div>
        <div class="col above">Two Above</div>
        <div class="col">Three</div>
        <div class="col above">Four Above</div>
        <div class="col">Five</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btmOne"></div>
    <div class="btmTwo"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}

.row{
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.btmOne{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:1;
}

.btmTwo{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:500px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:blue;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:10;
}

.col{
    float:left;
    background-color:lightgray;
    width:98px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    height:148px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;

    font-weight:bold;
}

.col.above{
    z-index:5;
}
```

To make the column come forward just add the class 'above' to the row.

See here for an example:

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Boldonglen/nBB7y/)